# How to use VisualStudio SignAndroidPackage in TeamCity?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, teamcity

I am using xamarin forms but I got stuck doing one of the build steps in teamcity while trying to automate building my solution.

Anyone able to give me an example of how to use VisualStudio SignAndroidPackage in TeamCity? For one of my build steps in teamcity, I chose my runnertype as visual studio and set targets to be SignAndroidPackage, configuration as release and my visual studio as visualstudio2017.

But I would like to know where and how I could specify the keystore to use for this particular build step just like how i can do it for the visual studio dialog as shown in the picture below.[image: Visual studio Dialog]

I googled and the closest answer I could get was from
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#releasemode

[image]

But the thing is how do I do the same thing when there is no gradle in xamarin.android?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a gradle file to sign the apk with Xamarin, you can just pass your project to msbuild with a specified build target which will sign and zipalign your .apk.

1. Specify the keystore properties (enable checkbox and fill in keystore/alias/passwords) in the project properties -> "Android Package Signing" under the correct configuration (e.g. "Release").
2. Add msbuild build step and select your Android .csproj as Build file path.
3. Set "Build SignAndroidPackage" in Targets (without quotes), this first builds your project and then signs the .apk.
4. Set "/p:Configuration=Release" in Command line parameters (without quotes) to select the preferred configuration. If your configuration contains spaces you can enter /p:Configuration="Release Foo".

Do not forget to restore the NuGet packages before this build step.
You can also set or override the keystore properties by passing the command parameters to msbuild: /p:AndroidKeyStore="true" /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore ="foo.keystore" etc...